# How URL parameters are mapped to an object on spring boot controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have controller like below

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public void callHello(MyObject myObject) {
    //code
}
```

Here MyObject is a POJO class with getter and setter

```
public class MyObj {
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    //getter and setter
}
```

I am calling this controller via ajax call as

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url:'hello?fName=testFname&lName=testLname',
    type:"GET",
    dataType:'JSON'
}});
```

This is working fine but I am wondering what is the feature of spring that automatically maps url parameter fname and lName and to field of myObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scene, there is a [WebDataBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html) that does the job. According to the documentation, this is a:

> Special DataBinder for data binding from web request parameters to JavaBean objects.

They are initialized with a [WebBindingInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebBindingInitializer.html). You can also create your own [ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer.html).

According to the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-web-binding-initializer):

> Spring MVC uses a WebBindingInitializer to initialize a WebDataBinder for a particular request. If you create your own ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer @Bean, Spring Boot automatically configures Spring MVC to use it.

Comment: Thank you Ortomala. Can you please help me understand if @ModelAttribute is no more needed in controller.

Comment: @user8710021 Can you please ask another complete question?